# XercesImpl in conflict with JavaSE 6's internal xerces implementation. Both are needed... what can be done?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xerces, java-6

I am sure that I am not the first to encounter this conflict.

The code that I have inherited does the following:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document dom; // declaration
javax.xml.validation.Schema schema; // declaration

...
...
...

javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new DOMSource(dom));
```

where the `...` stands for seemingly unimportant/irrelevant code

Compiling and running the code with JDK 6 works (and always had...)

Recently I have had to integrate into my code another component written elsewhere in the company. That component absolutely requires the inclusion in the classpath of `xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar`

I absolutely require this 3rd party component, *but* now running the code above no longer works and I get the following:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Root'.
 at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.beginNode(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
 at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:127)
```

As a solution, I have thought perhaps somehow to shield the xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar in a classloader of its own, but have not managed to do so, perhaps due to lack of classloader knowledge or perhaps because its not the way to go. One more thing about my environment, my app runs on tomcat 5.5 and 6...

by the way while debugging I have noticed that when I run `dom.getImplementation()`

- when adding the
  `xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar` to the
  classpath the result is
  `org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDOMImplementationImpl@5f15c`
- when removing it the result is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDOMImplementationImpl@6c6ae3`

*[No surprise to you careful readers I suppose]*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-N100EF

To use a newer version of Xalan-Java and override the one packaged with the JDK:

[use the Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/standards/). Place the xalan.jar, serializer.jar, xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar in the \lib\endorsed directory of the JRE, where  is where the runtime software is installed

Comment: I had done exactly as you had specified yet still the conflict. I guess since the code present prior to the addition of the 3rd party component utilizes the old API found in the JDK...

Comment: @Yaneeve - I think you have answered your own question. You are going to need to modify your code to use one or the other, I would go with the one that comes with the JDK. Maybe if you fully qualify your classes in each module that may work ? I would go with getting rid of the Xercesimpl you added and just making it work.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using:

```
// Uses first classloader-available implementation found:
//import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
SchemaFactory schemaFactory= SchemaFactory.newInstance(
    XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

Try using (Since Java 1.6):

```
// Uses org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory subclass 
//of SchemaFactory as implementation:
//import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
SchemaFactory schemaFactory= SchemaFactory.newInstance(
    XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI,
    "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory",
    null);
```

See the related JavaDoc.

Or use META-INF/services engineering: [article with examples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/extensible-137159.html)

Hope it still helps somebody.

Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try is to put the xerces jar in the endorsed directory. That will cause the whole JVM to use Xerces consistently. That may solve the whole problem right there, unless there is something special about 2.8.1 I don't know about.

Comment: Do you mean the jdk's endorsed lib or the tomcat's?

Comment: I was thinking the JDKs, but you can try tomcat's first and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's possible to endorse libs without modifying jre by setting [java.endorsed.dirs](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/index.html) system property.

See [what is the exact way to use Endorsed directory in jdk1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859471/what-is-the-exact-way-to-use-endorsed-directory-in-jdk1-6).