# Groovy classloading problems - XML parsers, Ant, etc

Tags: groovy, classloader

I'm trying Groovy for third time, and again, I've run into classloading problems.

I have a script which uses HTMLUnit (so it has it on classpath with it's transitive deps).
Groovy is on classpath as groovy-all.jar.
When I run the script, I get this:

Caught: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of ) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap"

Do I need to cut HTMLUnit's deps away, or is there a way to tell Groovy to use what's on classpath? Some switch which would mean, "don't complain about duplicite class appearance" or such.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the full shell command that invokes your Groovy script? Also your script code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to Groovy, the problem is that HTMLUnit depends on xercesImpl (see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html) and the JDK comes with it as well:

see

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-N100EF and

[XercesImpl in conflict with JavaSE 6's internal xerces implementation. Both are needed... what can be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110258/xercesimpl-in-conflict-with-javase-6s-internal-xerces-implementation-both-are-n)

Comment: Interesting, when I run HTMLUnit app without groovy, it works... How is that?

Comment: How did you include HTMLUnit? I tested it on Groovy 1.7 in groovyConsole with the following code snippet, and it worked:

`@Grab('net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.6')
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient

def client = new WebClient()
def page = client.getPage('http://www.google.com')
assert 'Google' == page.titleText
println 'done without error'
`