# Groovy Grape dealing with dependency resolution

Tags: groovy, xerces, groovy-grape

I am trying to use `org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8pre2` in a groovy script, but I get a Linkage error:

```
Caught: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface 
itable initialization: when resolving method  
"org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getOwnerDocument()Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;" 
the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the 
current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of 
<bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for  
the type getOwnerDocument used in the signature
```

I've already googled a lot and found a lot of answer like these:

[Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven)

[XercesImpl in conflict with JavaSE 6's internal xerces implementation. Both are needed... what can be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110258/xercesimpl-in-conflict-with-javase-6s-internal-xerces-implementation-both-are)

So, one solution could be to use javas `endorsed` mechanism to resolve the conflict, but I would like to make my script independent from such a "workaround". The script should run out of the box.

Next thing I was giving a try was to exclude the right dependency like this

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8pre2'),
    @GrabExclude('xml-apis:xml-apis')
])
```

but didn't succeed...

Any ideas?

PS: here is the script which creates the error:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8pre2'),
])
import org.w3c.dom.Document
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
def dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<html></html>".getBytes()))
```

Comment: Did not get any error with the provided script. `[#document: null]` was the result. *Groovy 2.2.1*

Comment: just gave it a second try and I get the error. `Groovy Version: 2.2.2 JVM: 1.7.0_09 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 8`. So it might be a problem with my configuration...

Comment: updated groovy and java - still same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx to @dmahapatro, I checked my configuration and found that I dropped some jars in {usrhome}/.groovy a long time ago. Removed these and now everything work like a charm...