# How to configure properly Jython project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, configuration, jython

im having little trouble with setting up Jython project in `IntelliJ Idea` with python plugin. Is there someone who knows how to do it correctly and can provide step by step instructions or support? Same project set up in `Eclipse` is working correctly but in Idea is having problems probably with Java integration.

Project consists:

1. Jython scripts to be run in Tests dir
2. Java custom libs as `jar` files in Java Libs dir

In general, what are the differences between `eclipse` and `intellJ` approach to project configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, again i will answer myself. We've managed to pin down problem, it turns out that IDEA probably is loading external libraries dif ferently, because it was using wrong lib (form jdk instead from our external lib). I've managed to use "endorsed" directory under jdk and now its working correctly. 
This [How to use endorsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110258/xercesimpl-in-conflict-with-javase-6s-internal-xerces-implementation-both-are) topic has some more info about how to achieve that.