# Is it possible to replace the version of the JAXB implementation in Java JRE 1.6 SE?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have this test class

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

class CompileTest {

   void foo( @XmlElement String in ) {
   }

}
```

my java version is

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and when I try to compile that  class I'm getting

```
javac CompileTest.java
CompileTest.java:5: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
   void foo( @XmlElement String in ) {
             ^
1 error
```

and that's valid for Java 6. When I tried to add newer JAXB library to class path, it didn't help. Is there a way to solve this?

```
javac -cp jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar CompileTest.java
```

Comment: The error is from the compiler, in effect, from a different (newer) version of the language. So replacing the jar will have no effect. Just curious, why don't you use Java 6?

Comment: I do not understand. "...from a different (newer) version of the language...", what? "Just curious, why don't you use Java 6?" I am, maybe it should be Java 7, it's because we cannot migrate from 6 to 7, while there is Java 6 in production actually...

Comment: @Betlista - Similar question and a solution is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211420/xmlelement-annotation-dissallowed-with-webparam

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the **Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism**

Put your `jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar` inside `<java-home>\lib\endorsed` directory.

Or, use the -D *java.endorsed.dirs* option

`javac -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/your/path/to/jaxb-directory CompileTest.java`

References:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/

Comment: I like the java.endorsed.dirs parameter, because I do not need to modify java installation for all applications...

Answer (score 4):

Use the concept of "endorsed libraries" folder. Take a look here:
[How can I make Ant use JAXB x instead of Java 6 SE JAXB classes ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235862/how-can-i-make-ant-use-jaxb-2-2-x-instead-of-java-6-se-jaxb-classes-in-javac)

Basically this is a way to instruct the JRE to use a more recent version of JAXB.

You can read more here:
[Unofficial guide to JAXB: Using JAXB 2 with SE 6](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Migrating_JAXB_2_0_applications_to_JavaSE_6.html#Using_JAXB_2_1_or_JAXB_2_2_with_JavaSE_6)
Also see this question:
[What is the exact way to use endorsed directory in JRE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859471/what-is-the-exact-way-to-use-endorsed-directory-in-jdk1-6)

Comment: I think Ravi's answer is better written than mine - please rather vote up @Ravi - I did!

Answer (score 2):

It can only be applied at field or method, not on method parameter. See

```
@Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({FIELD, METHOD})
public @interface XmlElement {
```

Edit: Source of XmlElement (JDK 1.6.0_18)

```
 * @since JAXB2.0
 * @version $Revision: 1.19 $
 */

@Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({FIELD, METHOD})
public @interface XmlElement {
```

So what I see is 1.6.0_18 version has XmlElement of 1.19 revision having only `FIELD` and `METHOD` target available.

Edit: So your problem is jdk 1.6 XmlElement isn't same as jaxb.2.2. you can check source at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.4/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.java?av=f

Comment: As I wrote "...that's valid for Java 6...", "...I tried to add newer JAXB library to class path...", where target is `@Target({FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER})`.

Comment: @harsh - In Java 6, it's declared @Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER}). See  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html

Comment: That's exactly why am I asking how to use the class from `jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar` with Java 6 if it's even possible.

Comment: ok, so when I look at the source of `rt.jar` version `java version "1.6.0_18"`, it shows only FIELD and METHOD. Edited my answer to include version information on XMLElement as well. Can you look at the source of jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar? your error reflects that its picking XMLElement from rt.jar instead of what you are intending.